# MongoDB connection timeout - permission denied

Tags: php, mongodb

I've installed the mongodb php library via composer and all that but I am running into an issue that has to do with permissions. Is there a way to see if it is running (which I assume it is, as I have an open connection apparently), and if so, how would I go about enabling permissions for this?

Here is the code:

```
    $client = new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

    $collection = $client->test->foo;

    $result = $collection->insertOne(['name' => 'foo', 'sex' => 'Male']);


    $find = $collection->find(['name' => 'foo']);

    foreach ($find as $entry) {
        echo $entry['_id'] . ' : ' . $entry['name'] . ' : ' . $entry['sex'];
    }
```

The exception message I got is:

```
    MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers 
    found (`serverselectiontryonce` set): 
    [Failed connecting to 'localhost:27017': Permission denied]
```

Thanks!

If anyone needs more information please let me know.

Update

I ran the command mongo on the system shell and this is what came up:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: test
2016-06-15T06:59:58.752-0400 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-06-15T06:59:58.753-0400 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error.
I had to restart mongodb to make this work.

I used the command below

```
sudo service mongod restart
```